# rails 3 rendering a partial from a collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to render a partial on a collection with `<%= render @posts %>` which returns the error:

`Missing partial posts/post with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}`

However it works if i use `<%= render :partial => 'post', :collection => @posts %>`

I have `_post.html.erb` in the same folder which uses `post` variable (from posts)

Why would the former example way of rendering a partial on a collection not work, but the latter example does work?

EDIT: I should specify I'm using Rails 3.2.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default of `to_partial_path` for your objects is always scoped under a view folder for the class, so your partial must be in the `posts` view folder.

When you use the form `render :partial => 'post'` it looks in the folder of the controller you are currently under.

I suspect that you are not working in the `PostsController` view folder, which would explain the behavior you are seeing.  If you are working in the `posts` view folder, then something else must be going on so if you could provide more detail that would help diagnose it further

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  I am in a different controller view folder, I didn't realize it looked for the partial in that way.